# TRL SFTTrainer - llama2 finetuning on Alpaca - datasettext field

Tags: python, large-language-model, llama

I am trying to finetune the Llama2 model using the alpaca dataset.  I have loaded the model in 4-bit and apply the peft config to the model for Lora training. Then I am trying to do TRL’s SFTTrainer to fine-tune the model.

The train_dataset is

```
Dataset({
    features: ['instruction', 'input', 'output', 'input_ids', 'attention_mask'],
    num_rows: 50002
})
```

This is the error that I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[28], line 3
      1 # Step 8 :Set supervised fine-tuning parameters
      2 from transformers import DataCollatorForLanguageModeling
----> 3 trainer = SFTTrainer(
      4     model=model,
      5     train_dataset=train_data,
      6     #eval_dataset=val_data,
      7     #peft_config=peft_config,
      8     #dataset_text_field="train",
      9     max_seq_length=max_seq_length,
     10     tokenizer=tokenizer,
     11     args=training_arguments,
     12     #packing=True,
     13     #data_collator=DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer, mlm=False),
     14 )


ValueError: You passed `packing=False` to the SFTTrainer, but you didn't pass a `dataset_text_field` or `formatting_func` argument.
```

If I try to pass the packing = True then I get this error:

```
ValueError: You need to pass a `dataset_text_field` or `formatting_func` argument to the SFTTrainer if you want to use the `ConstantLengthDataset`.
```

If I provide the dataset_text_field, which I do not know what it is.  I tried with "train" or "text" keywords and I am getting this error:

```
ValueError: the `--group_by_length` option is only available for `Dataset`, not `IterableDataset
```

I appreciate if someone can help me to understand the "dataset_text_filed", where do I set ConstantLengthDataset (does it come from packing?).  I also tried with packing = False and provide the dataset_text_field with 'train' and 'text' and they are incorrect.

based on the documentation:

```
dataset_text_field (Optional[str]): The name of the text field of the dataset, in case this is passed by a user, the trainer will automatically create a ConstantLengthDataset based on the dataset_text_field argument.
```

Comment: I tried with 'instruction' as a dataset_text_field and it worked.

Comment: Is 'instruction' the column name of your training df? How did you set the training text and label explicitly in your fine-tuning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dataset_text_field` (`Optional[str]`) is the name of the field in the training dataset that contains the text that will be used for training only if `formatting_func` is `None`.

You should be careful because if you do this:

```
`dataset_text_field='instruction'
```

SFTTrainer will only read the text saved in `train_dataset['instruction']`.
So that Llama2 will only learn to predict the instructions without the answers.

Each line of your dataset(`train_data`) should have a string saved in 'text' field like this:

```
train_data[0]['text']="<s>[INST]<<SYS>>You are an expert in math.<</SYS>>Compute 2+2 [/INST]4 </s>"
```

And you should do this:

```
`dataset_text_field='text'
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for this answer and can you please clarify a bit here for me?.
If you say the SFTTrainer will only read the text saved in train_dataset['instruction'] and only learn to predict the instrictions without the answer,
are you  intending to say that we are leearning only the instructions here without the model trained to predict the response?
I thought we feed the instruction and then we continue to predict tokens until end of sentence is hit, and then the prediction is compared against the expected output (which might be present in a different field in the dataset). Is that wrong?